# Laravel Function Mail Can't Sending to email

Tags: php, laravel, email

I'm currently having a problem with the sending email function in Laravel 10.

Here's the case I'm experiencing

- When I hardcoded the email address the email was successfully sent to inbox
- When I write the e-mail address from the e-mail data, no errors occur, but the e-mail does
  not enter the inbox

With Data : Email Not Send

```
$user = User::create([
        'name' => request('name'),
        'email' => request('email'),
        'password' => Hash::make(request('password'))
    ]);
    if ($user) {
        $mailData = [
            'title' => 'Send Password',
            'body' => 'Email From Register',
        ];
        
        Mail::to($user['email'])->send(new SendEmail($mailData));
        return response()->json([
            'data' => $user,
            'message' => 'Successfully Register'
        ]);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Failed Register! Try Again']);
    }
```

With Harcode : Email Send

```
Mail::to('myemail@gmail.com')->send(new SendEmail($mailData));
```

Thank You

Comment: Any errors? What does `$user['email']` contain? (`dd($user['email'])`) (shouldn't that be `$user->email`?)

Comment: Apart from checking that `$user['email']` does indeed contain the correct email addres, it could also be that the email was sent, but it was rejected/deleted by GMail. Is the content of the emails the same? DId you try both methods multiple times?

Comment: I got an email from input request, and returned according to the email that I input

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I tried sending with another e-mail account and different content, but it still doesn't send. But if I replace $user['email'] by writing the email directly, the email can be sent

Comment: @brombeer I've tried, with the code it still doesn't work

Comment: You could try `$user->email` instead of `$user['email']`, but that still means you need to check whether it actually contains the email address.

Comment: If the email given in the request data isn't a valid one for the domain you're sending the email from, either the mailserver may not accept it, or receiving mailservers may mark it as spam / suspicious. But as KIKO says, first do some basic debugging and check that the `$user['email']` variable actually contains a valid email address when you try to use it.

Comment: "_I've tried, with the code it still doesn't work_" What code exactly? Can you post the output of `dd($user['email'])` (before sending mail)?

Comment: @brombeer  This is return from postman https://i.imgur.com/X4YMisU.jpeg